# Passing parameters to the class while passing the class as a `class literal`

Tags: java, class, servlets, parameters, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a job using `Quartz` library. Below is the method belong to the class which schedules the job.

```
private void Reminder1()
    {
        String[] firstReminderTime = getFirstReminderTime().split(":");
        Integer firstReminderHour = Integer.parseInt(firstReminderTime[0]);
        Integer firstReminderMinute = Integer.parseInt(firstReminderTime[1]);

        if(firstReminderHour==null || firstReminderMinute==null)
        {

            return;
        }

        JobDetail job = newJob(PJob.class).withIdentity("p1").build();

        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
         .withIdentity(triggerKey("pTrigger1", "pTriggerGroup1"))
         .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(firstReminderHour, firstReminderMinute))
         .startAt(new Date()).build();

        try {
            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);


        } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Below is the job class.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package RemindeWorker.PJob;

import RemindeWorker.Listener.ReminderCommon;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import java.util.*;  
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  
import javax.activation.*;  

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */
public class PJob implements Job
{
    private String host;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String firstReminderTime;
    private String secondReminderTime;

    public PJob(String host, String userName, String password, String firstReminderTime, String secondReminderTime)
    {
        setHost(host);
        setUserName(userName);
        setPassword(password);
        setFirstReminderTime(firstReminderTime);
        setSecondReminderTime(secondReminderTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException 
    {
          String host=getHost();  
          final String user=getUserName();//change accordingly  
          final String password=getPassword();//change accordingly  

          String to="xxx@gmail.com";//change accordingly  

           //Get the session object  
           Properties props = new Properties();  
           props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  
           props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  

           Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
              @Override
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
              }  
            });  

           //Compose the message  
            try {  
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
             message.setSubject("Subject");  
             message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");  

            //send the message  
             Transport.send(message);  

             System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  

             } catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
        }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstReminderTime() {
        return firstReminderTime;
    }

    public void setFirstReminderTime(String firstReminderTime) {
        this.firstReminderTime = firstReminderTime;
    }

    public String getSecondReminderTime() {
        return secondReminderTime;
    }

    public void setSecondReminderTime(String secondReminderTime) {
        this.secondReminderTime = secondReminderTime;
    }

}
```

However I have an issue. Please pay attention to the below

```
 JobDetail job = newJob(PJob.class).withIdentity("p1").build();
```

Here we call the "class literal". But, I need to execute the constructor of the Job class, because it does accept the parameters. Passing parameters to this class is mandatory.

So my question is, since when passing the `class literal`, there is no way of passing the parameters, how I can pass them to the job class?

Comment: I believe a parameterless constructor is required when using the `JobBuilder`. And state in `Job` instances doesn't make much sense either. See [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Maybe this is an alternate? `.usingJobData("jobSays", "Hello World!")`

Answer (score 1):

Create `fake job` which:

- reads parameters from somewhere (properties, db etc)
- creates `real job` using constructor with parameters

and schedule this `fake job` to quartz.